# Correctly handle context.deadlineExceededError in golang

Tags: go

Is there a way to match a golang context deadline exceeded error by type in an exception handling switch?

```
switch err.(type)
case context.deadlineExceededError:
  fmt.Println("deadline exceeded")
}
```

won't compile, due to

```
cannot refer to unexported name context.deadlineExceededError
```

AFAICS since the type isn't exported, it can only be handled by string comparison.

```
package main

import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

const shortDuration = 1 * time.Second

func main() {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), shortDuration)
        defer cancel()

        select {
        case <-time.After(shortDuration*2):
                fmt.Println("overslept")
        case <-ctx.Done():
                err := ctx.Err()
                switch err.(type) {
                case context.deadlineExceededError:
                        fmt.Println("deadline")
                }
                fmt.Printf("error %T: %v\n", err, err)
        }

}
```

```
$ go build main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:21:8: cannot refer to unexported name context.deadlineExceededError
```

vs string comparison

```
        case <-ctx.Done():
                err := ctx.Err()
                errType := fmt.Sprintf("%T",err)
                switch errType {
                case "context.deadlineExceededError":
                        fmt.Println("deadline")
                }
                fmt.Printf("error %T: %v\n", err, err)
        }
```

```
$ go build main.go && ./main
deadline
error context.deadlineExceededError: context deadline exceeded
```

Comment: Use context DeadlineExceeded with errors.Is or ==.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `context.DeadlineExceeded` value ([documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/context#pkg-variables)):

- either for direct `err == context.DeadlineExceeded` comparison,
- or using `errors.Is(err, context.DeadlineExceeded)`.

Comment: Ah, so the type isn't exported, but a concrete value is. That helps. I would not have thought to look for constants when trying to match an exception data-type.